# Why my NodeJS express app shutting down after half hour of idle?

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

i have a nodejs application, which using express.
My problem:

- The app working well on localhost, until i stop that
- I bought a shared hosting on Namecheap.com and deployed my app
- Everything working, except one thing, this is the 24/7 availability
- After half hour of idle (When server does not get request(s)) application shuts down, until it gets new request, and this causes high load time
- There are no errors

My question is, is there anything that i can do to prevent this?
Like a custom code that does not let server to go idle?

Application uses: Express, MySql, Express-session, nodecache, Body and cookie parser, gz compression, nodemailer, path, fs

I am using pm2.
Code is long so i won't paste here, if you have suggestions i'll check and provide you more info!

(App registered in cPanel Application Manager powered by Phusion Passanger, NodeEnv=Production)

Comment: the woos of cheap shared hosting, use another host which has cron then wget's the site every 10 mins, support is here: https://www.namecheap.com/help-center/live-chat/

Comment: Thank your comment, that's true. It is a cheap hosting, and quality is bad :(